# Use Drupal 8 Rules to Create New Node

Tags: drupal-8

I am writing a reaction rule that responds to a Feeds import which creates nodes of type stub_node_feeds. I want to copy the title and a couple of fields to a new node of content type stub_node. I cannot figure out how to create a new node (is this an Entity of type Content?) using Rules. The "Create a new content" action seems appropriate, but it is not working for me.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution to my goal in a different module, CSV Importer. This module can import content entities, menu items, taxonomy terms, and users using data in .csv files. It does not attach itself to any of these entities, and so is the exact solution I needed.